# Basic C++ IOT Weather Station

Tags: c++, arduino

I am making an IOT weather station based on a particle photon that sends data via webhook to one of my other projects. I am very new to c++ and programming in general.

What can I do better with my code? What can be optimised? And what are industry best practices that I can put into place?

Here's my code:

```
#include <Adafruit_DHT/Adafruit_DHT.h>

#define DHTPIN 2 

#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
dht.begin();
}

void loop() {

delay(2000);

//Variables
//DHT11 sensor floats
float h = dht.getHumidity();
float t = dht.getTempCelcius();
float f = dht.getTempFarenheit();
float hi = dht.getHeatIndex();
//UV sensor floats
float sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
int UVLevel = 0;

//Error Retry
if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) 
{
Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
return;
}

if(sensorValue <=10)
{
     UVLevel = 0;
}
if(sensorValue <= 46 && sensorValue > 10)
{
     UVLevel = 1;
}
if(sensorValue <= 65 && sensorValue > 46)
{
     UVLevel = 2;
}
if(sensorValue <= 83 && sensorValue > 65)
{
     UVLevel = 3;
}
if(sensorValue <= 103 && sensorValue > 83)
{
     UVLevel = 4;
}
if(sensorValue <= 124 && sensorValue > 103)
{
     UVLevel = 5;
}
if(sensorValue <= 142 && sensorValue > 124)
{
     UVLevel = 6;
}
if(sensorValue <= 162 && sensorValue > 142)
{
     UVLevel = 7;
}
if(sensorValue <= 180 && sensorValue > 162)
{
     UVLevel = 8;
}
if(sensorValue <= 200 && sensorValue > 180)
{
     UVLevel = 9;
}
if(sensorValue <= 221 && sensorValue > 200)
{
     UVLevel = 10;
}
if(sensorValue <= 240 && sensorValue > 221)
{
     UVLevel = 11;
}
if(sensorValue > 240)
{
     UVLevel = 12;
}

//Serial Print DHT
Serial.println();
Serial.println();
Serial.print("Humid: ");
Serial.print(h);
Serial.print("%");
Serial.println();
Serial.print("Temp: ");
Serial.print(t);
Serial.print("C ");
Serial.println();
Serial.print("Apparent Temperature: ");
Serial.print(hi);
Serial.println();
Serial.println();

//Serial Print UV
Serial.print("UV Level =");
Serial.print(UVLevel);
Serial.println();

//Publish Data To Particle Cloud
Particle.publish("Humidity", String(h));
Particle.publish("Temperature", String(t));
Particle.publish("Apparent Temperature", String(hi));
Particle.publish("UV Index",String(UVLevel));
delay(5000);
}
```

For reference these are the sensors I am using:

[DHT 11 Temp/Humidity sensor](https://www.jaycar.com.au/arduino-compatible-temperature-and-humidity-sensor-module/p/XC4520)

[UV sensor](https://www.jaycar.com.au/arduino-compatible-ultraviolet-sensor-module/p/XC4518)

Comment: Indentation seems off, is this on purpose or a mistake from formatting?

Comment: The code is as is in my editor. Now you mention it, it does look odd. @yuri

Comment: @Xander Replace TAB characters by four spaces first before copying your code into the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume the indentation is an artifact of pasting the code here.

The big problem here is that long series of `if` statements.  A simple improvement is to make use of the `else` clause, along with knowledge of what values you've tested for already, it can be simplified to

```
if (sensorValue <= 10)
    UVLevel = 0;
else if (sensorValue <= 46)
    UVLevel = 1;
// etc.
```

But we can do better.  Since the range of values you're checking with is contiguous, and the result (`UVLevel`) is linear, we can set up an array to hold the data, then just use a loop to find the right place.

```
static values[] = { 10, 46, 65, /* ... */, 240 };
UVLevel = std::size(values);    // 12
for (int i = 0; i < std::size(values); ++i)
    if (values[i] <= sensorValue) {
        UVLevel = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

We initially set `UVLevel` the the maximum value so that if the sensor value is greater than 240 we get the correct result without having to check after the loop.

For a larger range of possible values, the for loop used here can be replaced with a more complicated binary search.